# How do I iterate through each column of data in a LINQ to SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Imagine my LINQ to SQL query is this:

```
var query = (from q in db.GetTable<potato>()
            where q.ID == dbID
            select q).FirstOrDefault();
```

How would I iterate *horizontally* instead of *vertically?*.  So there's just the one row, I want to iterate through each data item in a column per column basis, instead of row by row. There's quite a few properties so I'd just like to iterate instead of writing them all manually.

Comment: you mean each property in model??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data you want is *Property*:

```
var values = typeof(potato)
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(p=>p.GetValue(query,null))
    .ToArray();
```

If data is Field:

```
var values = typeof(potato)
    .GetFields()
    .Select(p=>p.GetValue(query))
    .ToArray();
```

If some property must be returned you can filter PropertyInfoes or FieldInfoes like below:

```
typeof(potato)
    .GetFields()
    .Where(p=>...labla...)
    .Select...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this through reflection

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in potato.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
    {
          string val= propertyInfo.GetValue(potato, null).ToString();
    }
}
```